# QRadar no listening on 514 port

Tags: syslog, qradar

I install a fresh QRadar community, and have configured a syslog event source.

But QRadar is not listening on the 514 port (no TCP nor UDP)

Do you have any idea ?

Here is the output of netstat:

```
[root@localhost ~]# netstat -nlp|grep 514
tcp6       0      0 :::1514                 :::*                    LISTEN      24177/syslog-ng
udp6       0      0 :::1514                 :::*                                24177/syslog-ng
```

Many thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with my fresh QRadar CE 7.3.3 installation. Syslog was not listening on port 514 and no other log events were displayed in real-time stream.

In `/var/log/qradar.log` the following message showed up:

```
Apr 10 08:48:43 ::ffff:X.X.X.X [masterdaemon.masterdaemon] [Thread-70] com.eventgnosis.ecs: [INFO] [NOT:0000006000][X.X.X.X/- -] [-/- -]Waiting for valid license...
```

Finally I found this [support article](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/updated-qradar-deploy-changes-31-december-2020-can-impact-product-functionality) on IBM's support pages. After updating the license file as described in the article everything works fine.

Comment: Thank you. I had to follow the same steps in Jan 2022 after a fresh install of CE 7.3.3. Some of the license files were there, but not all.